# Audio waveform in java finished coding but readings are different for waveform

Tags: java, audio, visualization, javasound, waveform

I have captured audio from mic and drawn a waveform of the recording, my doubt is will the waveform readings will be between -1+1 or +5-5 ?? my readings are between like 1000's.. could some one help??

Using code from internet (eg:SamplingGraph.java, CapturePlayback.java) i completed this.,

After recording i scaled and drawn waveform and scale readings in Jpanel., but the highest and lowest values of the waveform are like 3000 and -1890 some thing like tat.,

Comment: for drawing waveform my values are stored in int array, should that be in double array??

Comment: 1) You can edit your question.  Please don't put further information in comments. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please link to code samples, rather than just mention the name. 4) Unless you can fix this question up significantly (see points 1-3), I will be voting to close as 'not a real question'.

Answer (score 1):

Samples from microphone are almost always `short` type which are integers that range from -32768..+32767.  This seems consistent with the values you are seeing.  If you want them as `doubles` ranging from -1 to 1 fix them in a loop

```
double[] dSamples = new double[iSamples.length];

for (int i=0:i<iSamples.length:i++) {
    dSamples[i] = iSamples[i] / 32768.0d;
}
```

Comment: short ranges from -32768 to +32767. The above code will put your samples in the range +/- .5, not +/-1.